# Как в rust преобразовать doc в docx?

Tags: rust, docx

Мне нужно кросс-платформенное преобразование `doc` в `docx`, без скачивания сторонних программ, офисов и т.д. все на что наткнулся, это unicorn-rs

Comment: А зачем? Кто-то отрывает docx и не открывает doc?

Comment: @splash58 да, наш препод...

Comment: Выглядит как проблема XY - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Проблема_XY_(Ошибка_молотка)

Comment: Полностью согласен с предыдущим оратором ))